# Can string yy/bbbb be sorted by bbbb part?

Tags: python

So I have a text file that looks like this:

```
`year`; `index`; `firstName`; `lastName`

`year`; `index`; `firstName`; `lastName`

`year`; `index`; `firstName`; `lastName`

...
```

I had to make a id that takes last 2 digits of year (2019 - 19) and full index and makes it to look like this: yy/bbbb

I did that like this:

```
id = (str(int(`year`) % 100) + "/" + `index`)
```

How do I sort it by index part?

Example:

```
2019; 0701; Tom; Smith - Id looks like this: 19/0701

2018; 0305; John; Williams - Id looks like this: 18/0305

2015; 0413; Emma; Austin - Id looks like this: 15/0413
```

Output:

```
18/0305 John Williams

15/0413 Emma Austin

19/0701 Tom Smith
```

Comment: The sorting functions have a `key` parameter, you give it a function that extracts the key from each element.

Comment: You say the data is in a string, but in a comment you imply that it’s a list. Which is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have all of records in a list `ids` and you wanted to sort it in place you could do

```py
ids.sort(key=lambda x: x[2:])
```

This sets the value for sorting purposes to the slice starting at index 2 of each element.

Comment: Okay, it works, and it makes a 2d array. How can I make it into a list but without using numpy?

Comment: @Ik4a The result should be a list already, and what does NumPy have to do with this? I suggest learning some more Python, and about programming in general, before anything else.

Comment: @AMC The result is list of lists, and i need it to be a single list of all elements

Comment: @Ik4a Then you can just flatten the list, no?

Comment: @AMC How to do it without using numpy?

Comment: @Ik4a I still don't understand what NumPy has to do with this...

Comment: @AMC Never mind about that then, can you tell me how to flatten it?